# Whether xlsx engine in SAS scan all the rows to get variables'length?

Tags: import, sas, xlsx

Whether PROC IMPORT using **xlsx** engine in SAS scans all rows to get variables' length? I have a [whitepaper](https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/sas-global-forum-proceedings/2019/2991-2019.pdf) documented that **xlsx** engine will scan all the row to get datatype but no paper so far confirm that SAS will also scan all rows to get variables' length.

[image]

Comment: Post this on communities.sas.com where the developers and SAS employee's can answer your question. This will also vary by version and which engine you're using so you'll need to specify that as well.

Comment: @Reeza I did reply to someone in the community but because it is in the comment section so I am not sure it can get the attention. Maybe next time I will create a new post. Warm regards. I am using SAS EG 8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that is the definitive answer on the subject, as Vince DelGobbo is the resident expert at SAS Institute on working with Excel.  I don't know if he personally wrote the XLSX engine or not, but he certainly knows those things inside and out.  So we can trust him here - and if it's scanning datatype, it's also scanning length (as that's part of data type).

However, this is trivially verifiable, and I did so - excel file with '1 in every row in column A except the last row (2**20) with a 240-character long string in it.

PROC IMPORT returned a 240 long column, no truncation issues.